# TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

so I'm making a bot using selenium in python which makes an Instagram account and when I'm at the step where I code the action of the bot to enter the email id I'm getting this problem...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/akshatverma/PycharmProjects/wantfollowers/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    _email = browser_.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div")[0]
TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable
```

and my code is in the photo below...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfUKu.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error is cause you are using

```
find_element_by_xpath
```

with index `[0]`

Fix :

1. Use `find_elements_by_xpath` (plural)

**Code :**

```
_email = browser_.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div")[0]
_email.send_keys('dumdum')
```

2. Remove `[0]`

**Code :**

```
_email = browser_.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div")
_email.send_keys('dumdum')
```

Comment: so what do I do with the  _email.click() block?

Comment: What do you mean ?